# How do I implement a common validation method for several attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

I have a model with two time attributes as follows,

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :time1_must_be_in_the_past?
  validate :time2_must_be_in_the_past?

  def time1_must_be_in_the_past?
    if time1.present? && time1 > DateTime.now
      errors.add(:time1, "must be in the past")
    end
  end
  def time2_must_be_in_the_past?
    if time2.present? && time2 > DateTime.now
      errors.add(:time2, "must be in the past")
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to have one validation method that copes with both validations. How should this be done.

Answer (score 1):

From what you described, I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :time_must_be_in_the_past

  def time_must_be_in_the_past
    if time1.present? && time1 > DateTime.now
      errors.add(:time1, "must be in the past")
    end

    if time2.present? && time2 > DateTime.now
      errors.add(:time2, "must be in the past")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use followinf code snippet

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :time_must_be_in_the_past?

  def time_must_be_in_the_past?
    [time1, time2].each do |time|  
      errors.add(:time, "must be in the past") if time.present? && time> DateTime.now
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Close. The message I get is `"time must in the past"` for both attributes. I want `"time1 must in the past"` and `"time2 must in the past"`.